# Write $3-6+12-...$ using sigma notation in $2$ different ways.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

"Write $3-6+12-...$ using sigma notation in $2$ different ways."

I have got the first way, I simply do the infinite sum of $f(k)$ from $k=1$ to infinity, where $f(k) = 3(-2)^{(k-1)}$.

But I don't know how to find the second way. All I am observing is that the common ratio is $-2$, but I have implemented that in my first way. Maybe there is some arithmetic way instead of a geometric way....?

Any help please?

Comment: Also, I have tried "combining" 3-6, 12-24, 48-96 in pairs...

But what happens is you get the first term being -3, and the successive term being multiplied by 4.

However, when I put this into the infinite sum formula, my first 2 sigma notations derive different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach is a fine one.  The general term is $(-3)4^{k-1}$.  Finite sums should agree.  The infinite sums using the geometric series formula may not because the series is not convergent.  The absolute value of the ratio is greater than $1$ in both cases.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you. I just realized that you cannot compare infinite sums if the sequence is divergent.